# Audio won't be muted with JavaScript - removing audio tags with mutationobserver needed

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, mutation-observers

I tried to use the following userscript to remove all audio from a certain website:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        addicto
// @namespace   nms
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  let sites = ['mako.co.il'];
  let href = window.location.href;
  for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    if (href.includes(sites[i])) {
      Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach((audio)=>{
        audio.muted = true;
      });
    }
  }

  // If href includes the value of the iteration on the "sites" array, do stuff.
});
```

This code didn't work and I assume that observing all `audio` tags coming randomly and mutating the DOM is exactly what I need to better cope with this.

How can this mutation observer be written? I have never written a mutation observer and I feel as if this example would be very short and very basic and exactly what I need to get a taste of the code context of the logic which I just described and I would thank dearly to anyone who will try to show it to me and other people who are having a similar problem.

Comment: Might not be a problem but note that your script will not mute all possible sources of sounds that could be diffused by a tab, only the ones that are appended inside the DOM as HTMLAudioElement. It will miss all HTMLAudioElements that are not in the DOM, all video elements, all AudioContexts, and all of the above + appended to DOM if inside an iframe. If a real extension is an option, then it might be easier to use [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update) with the `update(tabId, {muted:true})` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enumerate `mutations` and each mutation's `addedNodes`
- Enumerate node's child elements because mutations are coalesced during page loading using the superfast getElementsByTagName instead of the superslow querySelectorAll
- Don't use `@grant none`, which runs your userscript in the page context, unless you really need direct access to the page's JavaScript objects
- Use `@run-at document-start` to mute the audio during page loading

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     addicto
// @include  *
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const sites = ['mako.co.il'];
if (sites.some(site => location.hostname.includes(site))) {
  new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for (const m of mutations) {
      for (const node of m.addedNodes) {
        if (node.localName == 'audio') {
          audio.muted = true;
        } else if (node.firstElementChild) {
          for (const child of node.getElementsByTagName('audio')) {
            audio.muted = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
}
```

Comment: Very interesting for me to read and I'm going to read it at least 2 or 3 more times before implementing. I have 2 questions please. Why is `(node.children && node.children[0])`? I mean if in the first portion (`node.children`) you go on all children, why do you mark the first of them (0) right afterwards?

Comment: Also, regarding `// @run-at   document-start` is it a must? I never used it in any of the 20 scripts I wrote. I understand that it is the default behavior anyway but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: 1. Text nodes don't have `children` so the first checks skips them, `children[0]` means "at least one element child" 2. `document-start` means the script processes the page as it's still being loaded.

Comment: Sorry, text nodes? You mean to `textContent`? I swear I **miss** the meaning here.

Comment: textContent is a convenient accessor for the actual [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text).